# Backup external hard drive to the cloud via Time Capsule

Tags: time-machine, backup, hard-drive, time-capsule

I'd like to move my photo directory to an external hard drive, but still have that hard drive backed up both locally and to the cloud. This wouldn't be a problem if I was using a desktop machine of some sort. However, I have a laptop, and I'd like for the external drive to be able to backup to the cloud without needing my laptop as an intermediary to the cloud. Is it possible to have an external hard drive that's connected to a Time Capsule backup to a cloud backup service (like CrashPlan) using the Time Capsule's internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - but the flow of the data isn't linked directly.

1. The external drive can be opted in to back up to any Time Machine destination as long as there's enough space on the destination drive.
2. You can configure CrashPlan to back up files from the external drive - directly to the cloud.

Note: These are independent - you could enable *1 and not 2* **or** *2 and not 1* **or** *both 1 and 2* as you wish. Getting Crash Plan to see files from within the protected Time Machine storage isn't something I would recommend.